# SharePoint Online SP.CamlQuery is undefined

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I'm implementing SharePoint Online Add-in
I need `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` data,
but `SP.CamlQuery` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SP.CamlQuery` is defined in `sp.js` but your code runs when `sp.js` is not loaded. So to overcome this use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` to delay execution of your code until `sp.js` loads.

Note: both have `SP` namespace but `SP.SOD.executeFunc` is defined in `core.js` file and is always loaded in SharePoint.

Code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', SP.ClientContext, function() {
    // do stuff, use SP.CamlQuery object
});
```